# Call a variable in a system command

Tags: r, imagemagick, system, imagemagick-convert

I'm calling image magick in an R script, which is working fine (see line 1). However, I'd like to get it call a variable from R and change the name of the output file depending on this variable. I've tried to paste it into the system command (see line 2), but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

line 1:

```
    system("magick convert -delay 40 *.png K-10 trail_cost - 3 K.gif")  # make a gif of all the photos
```

line 2:

```
    system(paste("magick convert -delay 40 *.png K - ", K, "trail_cost - ", trail_cost, ".gif"))  # make a gif of all the photos
```

Comment: Is it a problem that you have  `- delay` instead of `-delay`  (extra blank space)?

Comment: ah good idea, but still gives an error message: convert: unable to open image 'K': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3109.

Comment: There is an extra space after `K - "`, should be `K -"` ?

Comment: Two ideas: 1/ Create your final filename outside the command, save it to a variable and use the variable in the command. 2/ You should not have blank spaces in the filename unless it is all enclosed in " ". I can not understand why you would want spaces in the filename anyway as that can lead to other problems. Looks like you are using V7 so magick replaces convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some extra spaces, I would use *paste0* and check if identical before running:

```
K = 10
trail_cost = "3 K"

# check if identical before running system
identical("magick convert -delay 40 *.png K-10 trail_cost - 3 K.gif",
          paste0("magick convert -delay 40 *.png K-", K, " trail_cost - ", trail_cost, ".gif"))
# [1] TRUE
```

**Note:** Avoid using spaces in filenames.

```
K = 10
trail_cost = 3

paste0("magick convert -delay 40 *.png K-", K, "trail_cost-", trail_cost, "K.gif")
```